# Can anybody pinpoint the cause of this StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Trying to learn to program and once again losing all confidence because I think I've internalised a simple concept but something seemingly extraordinary is happening or it is just flying right over my head.

When I run the program I get a StackOverFlowException if I access the property by assigning a string to FirstName or SecondName

My Customer Class:

```
class Customer : ICustomer
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName;
        }

        set
        {
            FirstName = value;
        }
    }

    public string fName
    {
        get
        {
            return fName;
        }

        set
        {
            fName = value;
        }
    }

    public string SecondName
    {
        get
        {
            return SecondName;
        }

        set
        {
            SecondName = value;
        }
    }

    public string sName
    {
        get
        {
            return sName;
        }

        set
        {
            sName = value;
        }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return ID;
        }

        set
        {
            ID = value;
        }
    }

    public int mId
    {
        get
        {
            return mId;
        }

        set
        {
            mId = value;
        }
    }

    public int GetID()
    {
        return mId;
    }

    public void SetID(int id)
    {
        mId = ID;
    }

    public void SetName(string fName, string sName)
    {
        fName = FirstName;
        sName = SecondName;
    }
}
```

and the main program

```
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create unique string code based off current date and time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>code string</returns>
    static string generateUniqueCode()
    {
        string characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        string ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString();
        var code = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < characters.Length; i += 2)
        {
            if ((i + 2) <= ticks.Length)
            {
                var number = int.Parse(ticks.Substring(i, 2));
                if (number > characters.Length - 1)
                {
                    var one = double.Parse(number.ToString().Substring(0, 1));
                    var two = double.Parse(number.ToString().Substring(1, 1));
                    code += characters[Convert.ToInt32(one)];
                    code += characters[Convert.ToInt32(two)];
                }
                else
                    code += characters[number];
            }
        }
        return code;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates unique integer code based off current date and time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>integer code</returns>
    static int generateUniqueCode(int seed)
    {
        string characters = "0123456789";

        Random randInt = new Random(seed);
        var ticks = randInt.Next();

        int code = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < characters.Length; i += 2)
        {
            if ((i + 2) <= ticks)
            {
                var number = ticks;
                if (number > characters.Length - 1)
                {
                    var one = double.Parse(number.ToString().Substring(0, 1));
                    var two = double.Parse(number.ToString().Substring(1, 1));
                    code += characters[Convert.ToInt32(one)];
                    code += characters[Convert.ToInt32(two)];
                }
                else
                    code += characters[number];
            }
        }
        return code;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        int generatedIntCode = generateUniqueCode(1);

        customer.FirstName = "Conor";
        customer.SecondName = "MacFirbhisigh";
        customer.SetID(generatedIntCode);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} {2}", customer.ID, customer.FirstName, customer.SecondName);

        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: All your properties call itself which calls itself which calls itself .. and goes on.

Comment: Also there's no point in having a public property and public get and set methods that just use that property.

Comment: @SonerGönül and PatrickHofman are correct, but FYI those aren't the only problems with your code.  The code in SetName is backwards as well (the assignments are going the wrong way).

Comment: For your future reference, the way you find the cause of a stack overflow is to (1) run your program in the debugger, and (2) examine the *middle* of the stack at the point of the crash. The *last* thing on the stack was just unlucky to be there when the stack ran out. The thing in the *middle* of the stack is the thing that is doing an unbounded recursion.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this, please? Kinda know what the stack is, but I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 10):

In the getter and setter of `FirstName` (and all others), you are calling the same property over and over again. The endless loop you created will result in a `StackOverflowException`.

If you don't want to add custom logic to your properties, just use auto-implemented properties:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

If you did want to implement the property on your own, creating your own backing fields, this is what it should look like (this is effectively the same as what the above code would generate):

```
private string firstName; // backing field

public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        return this.firstName; // return the backing field
    }
    set
    {
        this.firstName = value; // set the backing field
    }
}
```

Comment: and for the sake of teaching them the right way to do it, `private string _firstName; public string FirstName { get { return _firstName;} set {_firstName = value;} }`

Comment: Why would you do that? That is what auto-implemented properties do, right? @DrewJordan

Comment: yes, of course it is, and I totally agree with your answer. I'm just saying they obviously don't grok how to use properties, and your answer (while correct and I upvoted) just tells them 'don't worry about not understanding it, just do it this way instead'.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks @DrewJordan

Comment: Thanks so much for the speedy reply. I see this used in a lot of tutorial/example code and I swear on my life I have used this format before without an issue, although you have fixed the issue so... 

Has something changed fairly recently?

@DrewJordan That makes so much more sense, thanks a lot!

Comment: No, you are mixing things up. @ConorMacF

Answer (score 0):

You left out a few important parts

Firstly, you always need to declare you variables,

public - for outside get and set, thus no need for the get-set methods.
private - get/set methods are necessary for data retrieval modification.

Also, see the SetName method.

Hope it helps :p

This should do the trick:

```
class Customer : ICustomer
{
    private string firstName;
    private string name;
    private string secondName;
    private string sName;
    private int iD;
    private int mId;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        set
        {
            firstName = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public string SecondName
    {
        get
        {
            return secondName;
        }

        set
        {
            secondName = value;
        }
    }

    public string SName
    {
        get
        {
            return sName;
        }

        set
        {
            sName = value;
        }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return iD;
        }

        set
        {
            iD = value;
        }
    }

    public int MId
    {
        get
        {
            return mId;
        }

        set
        {
            mId = value;
        }
    }

    public void SetName(string fName, string sName)
    {
        FirstName = fName;
        SecondName = sName ;
    }
}
```